# Not getting Bluetooth ACL_CONNECTED intent

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

We have an Android device which act as bluetooth sync like the bluetooth speakers, in which Android/IOS devices can connect with my Android device via bluetooth.
Every time when a new device pairs for the first time, I am not getting the ACL_CONNECTED intent in my app.
But when we unpair the new device from device bluetooth settings and again pair, then I am getting the ACL_CONNECTED intent normally.

Comment: Does the first device was already connected ? i.e before registration of Broadcast receiver .

Comment: No, first device was not connected